# Porque usar w150 w400 w800 em Picture com source > media?

Tags: html5

Uso a configuração abaixo sem indicar wxxx

```
<picture>
<source media="(min-width:1024px)" srcset="arquivo3/foto.jpg">
<source media="(min-width:500px)" srcset="arquivo2/foto.jpg">
<img src="arquivo1/foto.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

CONDIÇÕES DE USO:

- As fotos estão armazenadas por Largura iguais (e alturas diferentes)
- Arquivo3 = fotos Grandes (width=800 p/ uso em Desktop)
- Arquivo2 = fotos Médias (width=400 p/ uso em Mobile e Tablet)
- Arquivo1 = fotos pequenas (width=150 p/ uso em Mobile)

**DÚVIDA:**
Ví que alguns indicam usar  **wxxx** no srcset, conf. abaixo:

```
<picture>
<source media="(min-width:1024px)" srcset="arquivo3/foto.jpg" w800>
<source media="(min-width:500px)" srcset="arquivo2/foto.jpg" w400>
<img src="arquivo1/foto.jpg" alt="" w150>
</picture>
```

Fiz alguns testes de performance e não ví diferenças com wxxx e sem !!!

**PERGUNTAS:**

1ª) Colocar o w800, w400 e w150 **ajudam (mesmo)** o navegador a carregar mais rápido ?

2ª) Esta é a solução correta?

Agradeço antecipadamente aos colegas para dirimir as dúvidas

Comment: Olá, alguém pode responder? Creio ser uma dúvida pertinente e que pode ajudar outros tb. Obrigado.

Comment: Não é que "ajuda". Se você omitir, é o mesmo que colocar "1x" como string. De qualquer forma tem especificação, o que muda é se é densidade de pixels, ou largura (x ou w). Sobre o que é correto, só depende do seu caso específico (que tamanho a imagem ocupa na página na realidade). Quando você especifica a largura, o browser vai saber qual é a imagem mais adequada sem carregar. Quando você especifica densidade, ele tenta usar a mais adequada para a densidade do "CSS Pixel". Eu geralmente prefiro usar w e pré calcular caso a caso, mas vai de cada um.

Comment: Relacionado: [Trocar imagem em telas menores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244285/70)

Comment: Obrigado, Bacco. Como estou convertendo asp para php, e terei que refazer as linhas, acho que vou incluir os Wnn. Pela sua explanação, o browser irá interpretar e renderizar mais corretamente. Agradeço a ajuda, Qdo vc diz pre-calcular é usar media=(min-width:...?

Comment: Calcular o "w" adequado pra cada media. Por exemplo, se sua imagem ocupa 1/3 da largura da tela, em 960 px basta que ela tenha 320px em 1x, ou 640px em 2x.