# Trocar a imagem em telas menores

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<h1> Áreas de Atuação </h1> 
<div id="hr-atuacao">
    <hr>


    <div class="card-columns">

    <div class="card-img"> 

    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">
    <a id="botao1-card" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba Mais</a>


    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">




        </div>
        </div>




</div>
</div>





<div class="card-columns">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img id="civil" class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">  

    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">  
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../card.jpg" />    <!--Mobile-->
</div>

</div>

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">




        </div>
        </div>




</div>
</div>


<div class="card-columns">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">

    <div class="card-img"> 
    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png">




        </div>
        </div>




</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Existe algum jeito de quando eu mudar a tela para dispositivos móveis, a imagem que aparece dentro dos cards mude? Eu precisava colocar uma imagem menor e diferente quando isso acontecer mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: PS: Em HTML5 em teoria você poderia usar SRCSET e SIZES, pra trocar sem JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Answer (score 9):

Se fosse em CSS, eu recomendaria uma pesquisa por `@media` no site, temos vários exemplos, mas como você quer alterar uma imagem de conteúdo, vamos por outro caminho.

Em HTML5 você pode fazer sem depender de JavaScript usando as propriedades `srcset` e `sizes` da tag `img`.

```html
    Clique em "pagina toda" no snippet, e mexa no tamanho da janela do browser<br>

    <img class="img-fluid"
         src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x400/cccccc/000000"
         srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ffff00/000000  400w,
                 http://via.placeholder.com/700x400/ff00ff/000000  700w,
                 http://via.placeholder.com/1200x600/00ffff/000000 1200w"
         sizes="(min-width:1200px) 1200px,
                (min-width: 700px)  700px,
                400px"
    >
```

A especificação é meio confusa, tentarei simplificar:

- `srcset` é uma lista de *sources*, separada por vírgula, opcionalmente com um indicador de largura proporcional (ex: 100w); Enquanto não dominar a técnica, pode usar o equivalente em *pixels*, depois é melhor uma pesquisa mais profunda para entender a diferença para os *device pixels*;
- `sizes` é uma lista de *media queries* e respectivos tamanhos de imagem. No exemplo acima a imagem muda quando a *viewport* tem mais que 700px de largura (por isso a demonstração deve ser alternada entre tela normal e cheia). O último ítem da lista não precisa ter especificação de *query*.
- `src` é um *fallback*, serve para *browsers* incompatíveis, e é tratado como uma imagem `1x`

Documentação oficial da MDN:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Veja o suporte atual dos browsers no **[CAN I USE](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset)**.

Answer (score 7):

Uma alternativa é criar duas `div`s, uma com a imagem para *mobile* e outra imagem para desktop. Na div para *mobile* colocar a classe do Bootstrap `.visible-xs-*` e na `div` para desktop a classe `.hidden-xs`.

Para mais informações veja a [documentação do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities).

Answer (score 4):

Solução **CSS**

Uma opção é usar sua imagem como background no teu `css`(não sei se é possível no teu projeto):

```
.class{    background: url('../Imagens/saiba-mais-1.png') no-repeat;}

@media(max-width:600px)/*aqui você define a largura do dispositivo*/
{    .class{    background: url('../Imagens/saiba-mais-menor.png') no-repeat;}    
}
```

Reparei que no teu exemplo são 3 imagens iguais, se for usar diferente você pode aplicar a regra definindo um `id`para cada.

[CSS_Media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)